# TFS query to show items whose priority (Stack Rank) has been changed

Tags: tfs, scrum

We are using TFS to manage our backlog.

The PO believes that items priorities are constantly changing by team members other than her, which is far from ideal.

Is there a way to create a TFS query that tells me who has made the change, when, and if the change was applied to the Stack Rank? In our TFS set up the Stack Rank provides the items order in the backlog.

Comment: I think you can make a email notification every time a work items changes.  It will list exactly who changed what. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/track/alerts-and-notifications

Maybe someone is "drag and drop" you items in the backlog which changes the stack rank?!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39530090/how-to-create-a-tfs-alert-for-changes-to-the-items-stack-rank-field/39567538#39567538

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [team alert or personal alert](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/track/alerts-and-notifications) as Mat suggest,I have add an answer here [How to create a TFS alert for changes to the items' Stack Rank field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39530090/how-to-create-a-tfs-alert-for-changes-to-the-items-stack-rank-field/39567538#39567538)