# How to create a TFS alert for changes to the items' Stack Rank field

Tags: tfs, alert

How can I create an alert when any team member makes changes to the Stack Rank field (only) of any work item in TFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a alter filter in a work item  team alter just including **Stack Rank** changes

Sample:

[image]

---

Update

You can also try to use **TFS API** to achieve this. Below code shows how to query workitems whether a field (ex. System.AssignedTo field) is changed on a given day. For stank rank,  FieldName=`"Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StackRank"`

```
void Main()
{
    const String CollectionAddress = "http://mytfsserver/tfs/MyCollection";

    using (var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(CollectionAddress)))
    {
        var server = tfs.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
        var changes =
            server.Query("select * from WorkItems where [System.ChangedDate] = @Today")
            .Cast<WorkItem>()
            .SelectMany(wi =>
                wi.Revisions
                .Cast<Revision>()
                .SelectMany(r =>
                    r.Fields
                    .Cast<Field>()
                    .Where(f => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(f.OriginalValue as String) && f.Value != f.OriginalValue && f.ReferenceName == "System.AssignedTo")
                    .Select(f => new { wi.Id, f.OriginalValue, f.Value, f.ReferenceName, })))
            .Dump();
    }
}
```

More detials about how to programilly query work items, please refer the link from MSDN：[Query for Bugs, Tasks, and Other Work Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb130306.aspx)

Comment: can you do that in a backlog query as well? or only in alerts?

Comment: You can add a personal alert for your PM only.

Comment: Why you want to add a backlog query?

Comment: The query will be executed on demand as needed by anyone with access to it. Especially considering how busy our PO is. On demand query execution does seem more appropriate than emails. Does that make sense? @Patrick-MSFT

Comment: @aleafonso Afraid it's not possible with simple backlog query. Cause stack rank are binding to values in the query. And you can only choose whether = or > ,< the value in the query. You may have to use TFS API to achieve this. More details please see my update answer.